# Function that takes one explicit type

Tags: c++, types, compiler-errors, type-safety

How can I make a function that accepts, for example, a size_t but does NOT accept an int or any other implicitly convertible type?

Comment: If possible, consider replacing `size_t` with a stronger integer type that does not have implicit conversions. I'm obviously talking about a library solution, not any existing fundamental type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use overload:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T) = delete;

void foo(std::size_t t) {
    // ...    
}
```

Comment: Yep, that would be the nice way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename..., typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, std::size_t>>*...>
void f(T x) {}
```

Comment: (1) [Doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aa04f4357dd46e6) (2) Even if it did, you could bypass it with `f<std::size_t>(0)`.

Comment: @cdhowie It [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4fcafd04a814a66). Appears to be clang bug.

Comment: @cdhowie also added leading template parameter pack to prevent  `f<std::size_t>(0)`.